How to buffer, merge and save large spatial data from PostGIS to shapefile
I am using a PostGIS database (PostgreSQL 14, PostGIS 3) where I have a table layer_polygons containing layer polygons. It has a column geom containing the geometries and 5 columns for attributes value_1, ..., value_5. It is created by Django via ORM which I am using as a backend, i.e. my Django model is:
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class LayerPolygon(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField()
    layer = models.ForeignKey(Layer, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        db_index=True)
    value_1 = models.CharField(null=True, default=None, max_length=500)
    value_2 = models.CharField(null=True, default=None, max_length=500)
    value_3 = models.CharField(null=True, default=None, max_length=500)
    value_4 = models.CharField(null=True, default=None, max_length=500)
    value_5 = models.CharField(null=True, default=None, max_length=500)

Each polygon can also related to a layer.
Now I need to do the following:

Get all polygons of a layer (let's say layer_id=1)
Buffer them by buffer meters
After buffering polygons will probably overlap. Merge all overlapping geometries and also their attributes.
Put these polygons in a shapefile or geopackage.

I tried getting the polygons using Django ORM and writing them into a GeoPandas GDF, but for very large datasets (which I unfortunately have), this runs out of memory:
columns = ['layer_id', 'geometry', 'value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4', 'value_5']
results = list(
     tuple(LayerPolygon.objects.filter(layer_id=1).values_list('layer', 'geom', 'value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4', 'value_5'))
 )
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=pd.DataFrame.from_records(results, columns=columns), crs='EPSG:4326')

If I were only interested in the unbuffered geometries, I could load everything in chunks, write each chunk into a temporary shapefile (I tried it with this package, that works) and merge them afterwards or stream it into a geopackage or other file format.
However, this does not work, if I want to buffer and merge my polygons, since I could only do it chunkwise (using GeoPandas' buffer and dissolve functions) but I would need the whole GDF to really merge everything which will cause the memory issues.
Therefore, I was thinking about doing buffering and merging in the database (which lives on AWS and is scalable horizontally and vertically). I tried doing it stepwise using temporary tables, i.e.

Create a temporary table for buffered polygons
Cluster the buffered polygons using ST_ClusterDBSCAN
Create a temporary table for merged polygons with merged attributes
Query this table chunkwise

Here is what I tried to get the iterator:
from django.db import connection, transaction

def get_chunked_polygons(layer_id, chunk_size):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Step 1: Create a temporary table for buffered polygons
        cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_buffered_polygons AS
            SELECT
                layer_id,
                ST_Transform(
                    ST_Buffer(
                        ST_Transform(geom, 3857), -- Transform to a projected coordinate system (Web Mercator)
                        100 -- Buffer by 100 meters
                    ),
                    4326 -- Transform back to EPSG:4326
                ) AS geom,
                value_1,
                value_2,
                value_3,
                value_4,
                value_5
            FROM
                geo_layer_polygons
            WHERE
                layer_id = %s;
        """, [layer_id])

        # Step 2: Cluster the buffered polygons
        cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_clustered_polygons AS
            SELECT
                layer_id,
                ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, eps := 0.001, minpoints := 1) OVER () AS cluster_id,
                geom,
                value_1,
                value_2,
                value_3,
                value_4,
                value_5
            FROM
                temp_buffered_polygons;
        """)

        # Step 3: Create a temporary table for merged polygons
        cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_merged_polygons AS
            SELECT
                layer_id,
                cluster_id,
                ST_Union(geom) AS geom,
                STRING_AGG(value_1, ', ') AS value_1,
                STRING_AGG(value_2, ', ') AS value_2,
                STRING_AGG(value_3, ', ') AS value_3,
                STRING_AGG(value_4, ', ') AS value_4,
                STRING_AGG(value_5, ', ') AS value_5
            FROM
                temp_clustered_polygons
            GROUP BY
                layer_id, cluster_id;
        """)

    # Use a transaction block for the cursor operations
    with transaction.atomic():
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("DECLARE polygon_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT layer_id, geom, value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4, value_5 FROM temp_merged_polygons;")
            
            while True:
                cursor.execute("FETCH %s FROM polygon_cursor;", [chunk_size])
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
                if not rows:
                    break
                yield rows

            cursor.execute("CLOSE polygon_cursor;")

This worked, but it required using SQL instead of Django ORM. In addition, in my tests it was very slow. I tested it with smaller datasets where I do not run OoM and it was much slower than querying the whole data using Django and then performing the operations in GeoPandas.
Which solution would you advice to use? Memory usage is the bottleneck, but it should also not be too slow. How can I improve the SQL queries, if you propose to do the calculations in the database?

If you have a large dataset the conversion into shapefile will fail. Shapefile can be max. 2 GB. And if you have attributes with max_length=500, they will truncate because in shapefile the max length is 254 characters. Forget the shapefiles.

@user30184 unfortunately I am somehow bound to shapefiles but I think the problem is rather geopandas being extremely memory consuming. The length of the attributes in the database is 10, I should also change the Django model, good point!

@Bera I edited my question and added more details. And yes, I noticed that it crashed when creating the GDF for some layers.

If your objects are too large to fit in memory, they are too large for the shapefile format, which has hard limits in geometry, attributes, columns, cumulative row width, individual field width, datatypes, NULL support, frankly, there aren't enough characters in a comment to briefly summarize all that is wrong with shapefiles.  CSV, and just about every other format is better than shapefile for this task, but the fact that shapefile is not capable of meeting the requirements should play more heavily in your processing attempt.

@Vince then let us for the moment forget about shapefiles. Still my process was killed due to Out of Memory during the creation of the GDF. So I will still need some chunking and have the described problems even if I finally wanted to save my data e.g. in a geopackage. I will edit the question.

@Bera I added my SQL query and if you think this is the way to go, I would be thankful for answers or comments which help me to improve it. In the form I presented, it was quite slow.
There is a spatial_index on the geom column, this gets created automatically by Django.

On a side note, don't do anything distance related in 3857. Your buffer is now an ellipse. Use a suitable local projection like UTM, or rely on postgis geography (with caution, see this ) Don't use 4326 either for anything distance related, your clusters will also be an ellipse.

What exactly are these buffers used for, downstream? Is that some sort of a user-data database? Are those datasets ('layers') updated/extended frequently? Is the DB the main ingestion target for new features? These exports seem to be part of an on-demand service; do they have to happen in real-time?

An option that should work is to export the layer to a Geopackage and then do the processing using geofileops.
Geofileops is a package meant to speed up processing large geospatial vector files.
I don't have experience working with PostGIS, but I suppose that exporting the layer in chunks using geopandas should work. Another option is to try gdal.VectorTranslate.
Next, you probably will want to reproject the data to a projected crs, apply the buffer and do the dissolve. Those are easy using geofileops.
Script to illustrate how this could look:
import geofileops as gfo

# First reproject the layer to a projected crs
gfo.copy_layer(src=..., dst=..., dst_crs=..., reproject=True)

# Now we can buffer and dissolve
gfo.buffer(input_path=..., output_path=..., distance=...)
gfo.dissolve(
    input_path=...,
    output_path=...,
    explodecollections=True,
    agg_columns={
        "columns": [
            {"column": "value_1", "agg": "concat", "as": "value_1_concat"},
            {"column": "value_2", "agg": "concat", "as": "value_2_concat"},
        ]
    },
)

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of geofileops.
